# HTML code shown in emails sent

Tags: php, html, css, email

When I am sending a mail via PHP, I am using the PHPMailer class. However when I send the mail and look at it in Outlook I see that sometimes the raw HTML code is displayed. Anyone know why this could be?

[image]

Comment: you may be missed some tags or commented out

Comment: no, as you can see in the pic no tags are missed out

Comment: then this will work correct sometime and misbehave on some occassion right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to tell PHPmailer that you are rendering the mail as HTML.

```
 $mail->IsHTML(true);
```

Comment: Would this be in the PHPMailer class? or the page where i execute the mail sending?

Comment: In the page, after `$mail->new PHPMailer();` and before `$mail->Send();`

Comment: I just checked, and i already have these two:    $mail->IsHTML(true);
   $mail->IsSMTP(true);

Comment: try to comment the SMTP one then

Comment: Please show us the source code of the email, and header

Answer (score 2):

I think it's because of the empty space in the opening of the IMG tag.

```
< img src"{src}" alt="{alt}" />
```

should probably be:

```
<img src="{src}" alt="{alt}" />
```

Comment: yes exactly. If the other images work with the same exact code, then clearly thats not the problem

Comment: Dev.Bushido is right though, your HTML wont render properly unless you take out the space. `< img src="image/1.jpg">` is not valid HTML.

Answer (score 1):

`< img`      should changes to `<img`

You can check this [**example**](http://jsfiddle.net/NSnpD/)

Comment: I dont think this is the problem, because sometimes it works without showing the source code and other times it fails and shows the HTML code?

Comment: Just copy and create a HTML page from source,And check it.You can find how

Comment: Can you share the HTML source from outlook?

Comment: <img src=\"<site name here>/images/managed/{$row_min_file}_machine_medium.jpg\" alt=\"$row_object_title\" style=\"border-width:0px;\" /></a></p>\n";

Comment: No spaces in the code, but there is a space in the email

Answer (score 0):

Test your html code in HTML validation tool and fix accordingly.